# How to get the role id from user role table in asp net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have been trying to get the role id from Identity user role table. I can only get the role name using

```
var role = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
```

but I am stuck on how to get the role id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to get the role id

You can try following code snippet.

```
var roleNames = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

var roleIds = _roleManager.Roles.Where(r => roleNames.AsEnumerable().Contains(r.Name)).Select(r => r.Id).ToList();
```

Test Result

[image]

> trying to get the role id from Identity user role table

If you'd like to query `AspNetUserRoles` table directly, you can try following approach.

*Inject an instance of `ApplicationDbContext`*

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _appdbcontext;

public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, ApplicationDbContext appdbcontext
    //...
    )
{
    _logger = logger;
    _appdbcontext = appdbcontext;
    //...
}
```

*Query `AspNetUserRoles` table*

```
var roleIds = _appdbcontext.UserRoles.Where(u => u.UserId == user.Id).Select(r => r.RoleId).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you so much both worked but now I want to add this id to a table another model how do I that more like an update to the model

Comment: It keeps saying can not convert system collection generic list string to string. And if I change the tolist to to string I can not get the role id. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can do,

```
var roleIds = _userManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId()).Roles.Select(r => r.RoleId);
```

Comment: Thank you but I was getting an error that the name User does not exist in the current context. I am new to asp